# Allow/Block specific RPC interface UUIDs using the Windows Firewall

Tags: windows, security, firewall, windows-firewall

Is it possible to block/allow certain RPC UUIDs using the Windows Firewall?

For example, Active Directory domain controller replication occurs using RPC over TCP via the [drsuapi and dsaop RPC servers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-drsr/063618ed-b2e2-4983-ab13-3ed056700641) with UUIDs `e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2` and `7c44d7d4-31d5-424c-bd5e-2b3e1f323d22`, respectively.  I would like to create a rule that allows this traffic only from domain controllers and maybe from IT administrator subnets.  Allowing *all* RPC traffic is too broad as that increases the attack surface greatly since Windows exposes many other RPC servers(such as DCOM or the task scheduler).  Is there any way I can restrict traffic at this level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with the `netsh rpc filter` command, but documentation and examples are scarce. The best documentation is the netsh help:

**netsh rpc filter add condition /?**

```
Usage: add condition [field=]<string> [matchtype=]<string> [data=]<string>

Parameters:

       Tag           Value
       field       - One of the following values:
                     For layer = um
                         if_uuid if_version if_flag dcom_app_id image_name
                         protocol auth_type auth_level sec_encrypt_alg
                         sec_key_size remote_user_token local_addr_v4
                         local_addr_v6 remote_addr_v4 remote_addr_v6
                         local_port pipe
                     For layer = epmap
                         if_uuid if_version protocol auth_type auth_level
                         sec_encrypt_alg sec_key_size remote_user_token
                         local_addr_v4 local_addr_v6 remote_addr_v4
                         remote_addr_v6 local_port pipe
                     For layer = ep_add
                         process_with_if_uuid protocol ep_value ep_flags
                     For layer = proxy_conn
                         server_name server_port proxy_auth_type
                         client_token client_cert_key_name client_cert_oid
                     For layer = proxy_if
                         if_uuid if_version server_name server_port
                         proxy_auth_type client_token client_cert_key_length
                         client_cert_oid
       matchtype   - One of the following values:
                     equal
                     greater
                     less
                     greater_or_equal
                     less_or_equal
                     range
                     all_set
                     any_set
                     none_set
       data        - Value associated with the field paramter.

Remarks: Adds a condition to the RPC firewall rule.

Examples:

       add condition field=if_uuid matchtype=equal
                     data=11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
       add condition field=protocol matchtype=equal data=ncacn_ip_tcp
```

**netsh rpc filter add filter /?**

```
Usage: add filter

Remarks: Adds an RPC firewall filter.
         A rule and one or more conditions must be added
         before adding a filter.


Example:

       add filter
```

**netsh rpc filter add rule /?**

```
Usage: add rule [layer=]<string> [actiontype=]<string> [[filterkey=]<string>]
             [[persistence=]volatile] [[audit=]enable]

Parameters:

       Tag           Value
       layer       - One of the following values:
                     um
                     epmap
                     ep_add
                     proxy_conn
                     proxy_if
       actiontype  - One of the following values:
                     block
                     permit
                     continue
       persistence - Filter will be persistent.
                     This is the default.
       filterkey   - Uuid to uniquely identify the RPC firewall filter.
       audit       - Enable auditing for this filter
                     Only permit action type is allowed for audit rules.
                     Audit rules are not allowed at ep_add layer.

Remarks: Adds an RPC firewall filter rule.

Examples:

       add rule layer=um actiontype=block
       add rule layer=epmap actiontype=permit
                filterkey=11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
```

There are only a few examples I have ever found online, one is [this KB article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/SecurityBulletins/2008/ms08-067) that has formatting messed up but I happen to have a formatted snapshot:

[image: netsh example]

These two articles also have some interesting information:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/838191/list-of-remote-procedure-call-rpc-fixes-in-windows-xp-service-pack-2-a

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/rpc/load-balancing-best-practices